# Java crawler to crawl single domain and all its subsites

Tags: java, web-crawler

Ive been searching and looking at many different crawlers. But i am not quite sure which one to go with.

My goal is to search the full domain i.e `http://www.example.com` and all of it subsites i.e `http://www.example.com/page1`
Then afterwards be able to search through the different tags especially image tags to find their source.

So far only one crawler has caught my eye:

[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but you're asking not just for crawler but for HTML analyzer - something that would understand html tags...

If so, you can go with JSoup or even parse with regular expressions.

If you really need a crawler, you might find [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) to be a descent open source crawler

Hope this helps

Comment: I think actually HTML analyzer is exactly the right word to use in this case. Do you know if JSoup allows me to crawl every subsite of the domain even if i "don't know" all the specefic locations on the site? i.e so only by typing www.example.com it will find and analyze all subsites of example.com?

Comment: I think JSoup is not intended to do so, its an HTML analizer,not a crawler. There is no technical way to analyze all subsites of example.com, because crawler can't know the addresses on which the pages are available. Instead the crawler starts with some 'seed data' (like www.example.com) and looks for links inside the page, then it 'crawls' - downloads the pages available by these links, looks for additional links there, and so forth. You can think about this process as a graph traversal, for example. So I think you should use both Nutch (any other crawler) and JSoup.

Comment: Nope :) Nutch - crawls, JSoup only maps tags :) Crawler takes data (pages) from internet and downloads them into your hard drive as a series of files. JSoup can read this file and parse (extract tags and so on).

Comment: so Jsoup does not look at all the subsites?